# Setting a default order for a model's association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have 2 models, Category and Article; given the following association:

Category `has_many :articles`.. and Article `belongs_to :category`

If I do.. `Article.all` I get an array back in ASC order.

Now, Rails allows me to query a Category's Articles with: `Category.find(:id).articles`... but in doing so I get an array back in DESC order.. is there a way to override the default behavior of this so that I can order this array using x column in the Article's table without having to chain .order('column_name') everywhere I do this?

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the order when define association.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :order => "updated_at DESC"
end
```

For `Article.all`'s order, you could define the `default_scope`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('updated_at DESC') }
end
```

Comment: I feel dumb ha-ha; of course it had to be that simple! thanks!